# matlab parcial equation with 2 intervals

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Here is the code I have so far :

```
function [u]=example222(xrange,trange,uinit,u0bound,uLbound);
    n = length(xrange);
    m = length(trange);
    u = zeros(n,m); %%%
    Dx = (xrange(n)-xrange(1))/(n-1);
    Dt = (trange(m)-trange(1))/(m-1);
    u(:,1)=uinit';
    u(1,:)=u0bound;
    u(n,:)=uLbound;

     gegu=0.08;
     alpha=0;
     koefa=(-Dt*gegu/(2*Dx));
     koefb=(alpha*Dt/(Dx)^2);

u

   %  first time step
   for i = 2:n-1

   u(i,2) = u(i,1)+2*koefa*(u(i+1,1)-u(i-1,1))+(koefb/2)*(u(i-1,1)-2*u(i,1)+u(i+1,1))
   end;

        % subsequent time steps
        for j = 2:m-1
            for i = 2:n-1

              u(i,j+1)=u(i,j-1)+koefa*(u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,j))+koefb*(u(i-1,j)-2*u(i,j)+u(i+1,j))
            end;

        end;
        ______________________________________

x = (0:0.1:1);           
t = (0:0.8:8) ;           


u0=zeros;uL=zeros; 

uinit=1-(10*x-1).^2;


[u]=example222(x,t,uinit,u0,uL);

surf(x,t,u,'EdgeColor','black')
```

Next thing I need to do is to implement an interval for  uinit=1-(10*x-1).^2

IF  x-0.08*t < 0.2. then => uinit=1-(10*x-1).^2; 
else uinit=0;

Can someone help me with that please. I was trying to do it with if clauses and loops and couldn't make it work. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to define a piecewise function my usual method is as follows:

```
uinit = zeros(size(x));
I = x<(0.08*t+0.2); %// Find the indices where x<(0.08*t+0.2)

uinit(I) = 1-(10*x(I)-1).^2;
```

This case is easier than what you may often have since you want all the other values of `uinit` to be zero. If you had another function in the other region (say `x^2`) you could also do:

```
uinit(1-I) = x(1-I).^2;
```

The operation `1-I` gives 0 where `I==1` and 1 where `I==0`, therefore your get the complement of `I`.